# Zend Framework: Get Referrer Page?

Tags: zend-framework

Is there any way in Zend Framework to grab the url of the page the user visited last?

I don't really want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the HTTP referrer?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

MWOP has put a good post here showing you how to get HTML headers (including referer).

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Referer-td3007321.html

```
// In an action method of a controller
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->getHeader('referer');
```

Answer (score 11):

From a controller method:

```
$this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER')
```

basically the same as using $_SERVER, but without causing problems in unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in Module.php?

I have find a small solution

$headers = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request;

$headers->getServer('HTTP_REFERER')