# How to get previous visited page url in zend framework1?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have to add some condition in my code with respect to previous page I visited or URL where I visited.So How can I get that?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10740586/367624

Answer (score 0):

You can get previous page url using: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: @Parimal Did you check that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249274/redirect-to-previous-page-in-zend-framework ?

Comment: Yes I used $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; but it gives me current page URL.