# How to get HTTP_REFERER in Zend Framework

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, http-referer, referer

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740491/zend-framework-get-referrer-page) solution, but it doesn't work for me. My `$this` doesn't have `getRequest()` method and `Zend\Http\Request` doesn't have it too at all.

I tried something like

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
$http_referer = $request->getHeader('referer');
```

but it returns just `boolean false`. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, I'm using the wrong class. We need to use `\Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request()` This one is correct:

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();
$http_referer = $request->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
```